# Векторное изображение низкого качества в Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-studio, vector-drawable

Векторное изображение "Дверей" по неизвестной причине плохого качества только на **Android 5.0**
[image: Сильно мылит]

На Android 7.1.2 иконка отлично отображается 
[image: Отлично отображает на Android 7.1.2]

**ic_vector_exit.xml**

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="53.0"
    android:viewportWidth="53.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#556080" android:pathData="M0.5,0l0,46l22,0l12,0l0,-17l0,-12l0,-17z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#7383BF" android:pathData="M22.5,7l-22,-7l0,46l22,7z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M39.5,35L51.5,23"
        android:strokeColor="#EFCE4A" android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M39.5,11L51.5,23"
        android:strokeColor="#EFCE4A" android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M51.5,23L27.5,23"
        android:strokeColor="#EFCE4A" android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Приведите код изображения, с которым нет проблемы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915248/7566397 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо добавить строчку  `android:scaleType='fitXY'` в векторный ImageView
Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]