# Сжимается SVG в android

Tags: android, svg

Не могу понять и найти никакой информации почему на некоторых телефонах сжимается качество SVG drawable

Проверял на нескольких моделях:

- Huawei (<720p): Сжимается
- MEIZU (1080p): Сжимается
- Xiaomi (720p):Норм
- LeEco (1080p): Норм

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.jellyweb.machineryoccupancy.AddMachineryActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTypeAdd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/BulldozerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="ru.jellyweb.machineryoccupancy.AddMachineryActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_add_machinery">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/typeBlocks">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/photo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chooseImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_photo"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chooseTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/chooseTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:text="Выберите фотографию техники"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

SVG (@drawable/ic_add_photo) :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <group>
        <clip-path android:pathData="M24,24H0V0h24v24z M 0,0" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M3 4V1h2v3h3v2H5v3H3V6H0V4h3zm3 6V7h3V4h7l1.83 2H21c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2v12c0 1.1,-.9 2,-2 2H5c-1.1 0,-2,-.9,-2,-2V10h3zm7 9c2.76 0 5,-2.24 5,-5s-2.24,-5,-5,-5,-5 2.24,-5 5 2.24 5 5 5zm-3.2,-5c0 1.77 1.43 3.2 3.2 3.2s3.2,-1.43 3.2,-3.2,-1.43,-3.2,-3.2,-3.2,-3.2 1.43,-3.2 3.2z"
        android:fillColor="#000000"/>
    </group>
</vector>
```

[image: Не сжато]
[image: Сжато]

Comment: Картинки хорошо конечно, но нужен код вашего бульдозера, чтобы понять проблему И поспешите  добавить код в свой вопрос, пока его не закрыли, как вопрос на который невозможно ответить.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Добавил активити и свг.

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться, какие API на устройствах. Дело в том, что для API меньше 21 (Android 5) должна быть подключена библиотека поддержки `VectorDrawable`, иначе для таких API векторные изображения будут конвертироваться в растровые и соответственно "замыливаться". Если библиотека поддержки подключена, то смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/795482/177345) и возможно, [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767797/177345)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог один из ответов из этой темы с использованием vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936590/why-isnt-my-vector-drawable-scaling-as-expected/34936674

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы продемонстрировать причины разных размеров иконок на разных моделях смартфонов я перевел команды андроида svg в чистый svg.

- При `720dpi 1dp = 2px`  Поэтому я выставил `width="48"`  `height="48"`
  `viewBox="0 0 24 24"`. Здесь 1 реальный пиксель иконки,
  нарисованный в векторном редакторе растягивается до 2-х пикселей
  дисплея. Масштаб получается 2:1

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="48"   height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
     <defs>
        <clipPath id="camera">
  <path d="M24,24H0V0h24v24z M 0,0" fill="none" stroke="#fff" />
  </clipPath>
     </defs>
 <path
        d="M3 4V1h2v3h3v2H5v3H3V6H0V4h3zm3 6V7h3V4h7l1.83 2H21c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2v12c0 1.1,-.9 2,-2 2H5c-1.1 0,-2,-.9,-2,-2V10h3zm7 9c2.76 0 5,-2.24 5,-5s-2.24,-5,-5,-5,-5 2.24,-5 5 2.24 5 5 5zm-3.2,-5c0 1.77 1.43 3.2 3.2 3.2s3.2,-1.43 3.2,-3.2,-1.43,-3.2,-3.2,-3.2,-3.2 1.43,-3.2 3.2z"
         fill="#000000" clip-path="#camera"/>
    
</svg>
```

- При разрешении `1080dpi 1dp=3px`. Поэтому `width="72"`   `height="72"`
  Масштаб 3:1.  Картинка должна выглядеть крупнее:

```html
 


<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="72"   height="72" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
     <defs>
        <clipPath id="camera">
  <path d="M24,24H0V0h24v24z M 0,0" fill="none" stroke="#fff" />
  </clipPath>
     </defs>
 <path
        d="M3 4V1h2v3h3v2H5v3H3V6H0V4h3zm3 6V7h3V4h7l1.83 2H21c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2v12c0 1.1,-.9 2,-2 2H5c-1.1 0,-2,-.9,-2,-2V10h3zm7 9c2.76 0 5,-2.24 5,-5s-2.24,-5,-5,-5,-5 2.24,-5 5 2.24 5 5 5zm-3.2,-5c0 1.77 1.43 3.2 3.2 3.2s3.2,-1.43 3.2,-3.2,-1.43,-3.2,-3.2,-3.2,-3.2 1.43,-3.2 3.2z"
         fill="#000000" clip-path="#camera"/>
    
</svg>
```

Но размеры экранов смартфонов с разными разрешениями 720dpi и 1089dpi имеют одинаковый размер дисплея, допустим 5 дюймов.
 И иконки при этом должны быть по размеру одинаковыми, разумеется с разным качеством изображения.
 Чтобы достичь этого разработчики смартфонов делают перерасчет финального размера иконки средствами программ для  процессора смартфона. У разных моделей смартфонов свои алгоритмы перерасчета, поэтому финальные размеры иконок могут отличаться.

*Чтобы найти компромисс между разными моделями, попробуйте поиграться с параметрами :*

```
   `android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"`
```

Comment: Понимаете, в Android свои особенности работы и причины из области WEB тут обычно на последнем месте, наиболее [вероятно это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805106/Сжимается-svg-в-android#comment1273553_805106)/ В любом случае, чтобы отвечать на этот вопрос в "разрезе" Android, в нем недостаточно информации для определения проблемы.